# Custom payment gateway in magento2 redirect

Tags: magento2

I have to convert a custom payment gateway from magento 1.8 to 2.05,
I have created a payment module in magento2, but it is not redirecting to payment gateway url on place order.
When i select the custom payment gateway and click on place order it creates an order in backend and then redirects to the success page where there is option of pay.
Please let me know how can i fix this issue.

My requirement is that when user clicks on the place order button, it should redirect to payment gateway and then on successfully paying the amount it should redirect to success page.

Thanks in advance.

If any one have created  a sample payment gateway which redirect to payment gateway url after place order it will be helpful.